# Как установить opengl для visual studion 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

только начал изучать c++, ну и начал натыкаться на проблемы.
Подскажите как установить openGl на vs2017 ?
В интернете откопал либо видео 2013 года, либо какой-то glut, даже скачав его с офф  в доке не нашел внятного, для себя способа его установить. Также в процессе поиска наткнулся на всякие freeglut, grew и прочее, как я понимаю, библиотеки.
Если не затруднит объясните как, куда и откуда устанавливать openGL ?
Думаю информация будет полезна и другим чайника :)

Comment: Нет единственного правильного способа "установить OpenGL". Вам нужно выбрать и поставить две библиотеки: для открытия окна, и для загрузки функций OpenGL (второе - специфика Windows). Для открытия окна подойдут SDL2, GLFW, FreeGLUT. Есть еще просто GLUT, но он довольно старый. Для загрузки функций OpenGL традиционно используют GLEW, из неплохих вариантов есть еще GLAD. Для начала выберите две любые (я бы посоветовал SDL2+GLEW). Сейчас вы по сути просите вам личный гайд написать, но их в гугле и так довольно много. Я бы лучше попробовал какой-нибудь, и спрашивал о конкретных проблемах.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , Спасибо за ответ ! Вот на примере SDL2. Я зайдя на [сайт](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) нашел 2 версии: `Source Code` и `Development Libraries` в каждой тонна файлов, и папок (в `dev` папок меньше), и вот, я озадачился все ли нужно копировать ? Какие версии библиотек качать (`dev` или `source code`) ? На примерах в видео видел, как скачивали 3-5 файлов и подключали `./папка/file.h` а тут целый список файлов. (*я из веба, мне не привычно, когда библиотека - не 1 файл. Это норма ?)

Comment: Я же говорю, поищите гайды, там написано что качать. Вам нужен один архив, скорее всего `SDL2-devel-2.0.9-VC.zip`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, поставьте в ответ, помечу правильным. Спасибо ! ;)